# При скачивании файла в браузере Edge открывается пустая вкладка и автоматически не закрывается

Tags: javascript, html, вёрстка

Помогите разобраться. Есть ссылка на скачивание файла (программы). Если к ней прописать атрибут target="_blank", то при клике во всех браузерах открывается новая пустая вкладка, затем начинается загрузка файла и вкладка автоматически закрывается. Так работает везде, кроме браузера Edge. Там вкладка остается открытой, а диалог на сохранения загружаемого файла появляется в предыдущей вкладке.

Пример можно посмотреть здесь (ссылка "с сайта разработчика" и ниже еще ссылки):

```
http:// www.softportal.com/get-44132-picotorrent.html
```

Но я также нашел сайты, на которых нет такой проблемы, и не пойму почему. Вот пример:

```
http:// newprograms.ru/downloads-hamachi.html
```

Здесь в Edge пустая вкладка не остается висеть открытой, она закрывается также как и в других браузерах. Почему, в чем разница, как сделать также?

Answer (score 0):

Просто используйте аттрибут download.

```html
<a 
  download="text.txt" 
  href="data:application/octet-stream,hello%20world"
  target="_blank">Download me</a>
```

- **внимание**, для data-uri пишут, что старый Edge будет падать, но я его привел здесь как простой способ показать как будет работать.
- этот аттрибут подчиняется [same-origin policy](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0)
- `target = "_blank"` будет работать для браузеров не поддерживающих download, новые браузеры не должны открывать новую вкладку, если есть download

Ещё один вариант - поменять mime-type на стороне сервера, тогда браузер не будет пытаться рендерить файл вообще и `target="_blank"` будет не нужным.

[пара примеров](https://plnkr.co/edit/aVKSUYd2oFsEYdyaZQOM?p=preview)

Comment: У меня браузер и так файлы не рендерит, там смысл не в этом, он все файлы качает, не открывает.  target="_blank" стоит на случай, если ссылка перестанет работать, или программа перестанет запускаться, чтобы текущая страница с подсказками была открыта.

Comment: Хочется все же понять, как работает target="_blank" в Edge во втором примере

Comment: в первом примере ссылка на страницу, которая в итоге делает location.replace через js, во втором примере ссылка на сам файл.

Comment: чем вам помогает `target="_blank"` я так и не понял, разве что счетчиков аналитикса навешать как-то странно. если вы сделаете "download" то прехода не будет, даже если будет 404.

Comment: Некоторые программы блокируют антивирусы, например CCleaner антивирус Nod32 считал нежелательным несколько недель назад (может и сейчас тоже, не проверял). При попытке его скачать открывалось окно с сообщением NOD32 о блокировке - я думаю лучше открывать такие окна в новой вкладке, поэтому я проставляю ко всем ссылкам target="_blank" по умолчанию.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, теперь понятно, во втором примере стоит прямая ссылка на программу, а в первом - через редирект. Если поставить прямую ссылку на скачивание, то открывается новая вкладка в Edge и уже в ней предлагается сохранить файл, а не в предыдущей.